# Use std::vector to construct a object and use it

Tags: c++, stl

I need to avoid the additional cost of copying and destructing the object contained by a std::vector caused by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2745350/c-destructor-issue-with-stdvector-of-class-objects).

Right now I'm using it as a std::vector of pointers, but I can't call std::vector::clear() without deleting each object before nor I can use std::auto_ptr with std containers.

I wanted to do something like this:

```
vector<MyClass> MyVec;
MyVec.push_back();
MyClass &item = MyVec.back();
```

This would create a new object with the default constructor and then I could get a reference and work with it.

Any ideas on this direction?

**RESOLVED**: I used @MSalters answer with @Moo-Juices suggestion to use C++0x rvalue references to take vantage of std::move semantics. Based on [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd293665.aspx).

Comment: Is C++0x an option for you so you can take advantage of std::move semantics?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Almost there:

```
vector<MyClass> MyVec;
MyVec.push_back(MyClass()); // Any decent compiler will inline this, eliminating temporaries.
MyClass &item = MyVec.back();
```

Comment: I've resolved using this AND using C++0x std::move semantics (according to this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd293665.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

[Boost.PointerContainer](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_44_0/libs/ptr_container/doc/ptr_container.html) classes will manage the memory for you.  See especially [ptr_vector](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_44_0/libs/ptr_container/doc/ptr_vector.html).

With the container `boost::ptr_vector<T>` you can use `push_back(new T);`, and the memory for `T` elements will get freed when the container goes out of scope.

Comment: Although as we had yesterday, beware that `push_back(new T);` offers no exception guarantee - it can create the T and then throw, leaking the object (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4185350/is-it-safe-to-push-back-dynamically-allocated-object-to-vector/4185460). However, as Steve himself said yesterday, if the rest of your program/OS isn't robust, then there may be no need for this one line to be any better.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of storing objects, store shared_ptr. This will avoid object copying, and will automatically destruct the object when removed from the vector.

Comment: Or `unique_ptr`, which is much cheaper if you know the vector will own the objects pointed to.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with resize, which will default construct any additional objects it has to add to the `vector`:

```
vector MyVec;
MyVec.resize(MyVec.size() + 1);
MyClass &item = MyVec.back();
```

But do consider why you need to do this. Has profiling really shown that it's too expensive to copy the objects around? Are they non-copyable?