# Multiple template class destruction?

Tags: c++, vector, destructor

This is a simple test:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

class C
{
public:
    int _a;
    C(int a) { cout << "constructor C: " << (_a = a) << endl; }
    ~C()     { cout << "destructor C: "<< _a << endl; }
};

int main()
{
    vector<C> vec;

    for(int i=0; i<2; i++)
        vec.push_back(i+1);

    cout << "Go out --->\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
constructor C: 1
destructor C: 1
constructor C: 2
destructor C: 1
destructor C: 2
Go out --->
destructor C: 1
destructor C: 2
```

It looks not so funny when C is a real class with responsible destructor.
Any suggestions?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: same issue as here -> http://stackoverflow.com/q/2745350/476681

Comment: You should really define (or forbid!) a full set of constructors and assignment operators for non-trivial classes like this ;-). Then you would see (and properly implement) or forbid assignments and copyings of your objects, e.g. in and out of containers.  BЈовић's link illustrates the issues.

Comment: Interestingly we have three destructions for 1, but "only" two for 2. The reason is the vector growing by reallocation, thereby copying the previous elements (here 1)  and destroying the old ones. As noted, the copying is not logged, but the destruction is. Ah I see, Vlad made the same observation :-)

Answer (score 5):

You get multiple class destructor logs because there is object copy when adding object in a vector. Log also in the copy contructor, you'll see it balances out. As indicated in the comments, if you are using C++11, also log in the move constructor.

That is why if object construction is expansive, you use pointers(smart_ptr) in vector. Or reserve enough space and use emplace_back(again if using C++11).

Comment: Or possibly, the move constructor.

Comment: Move constructor would be the better solution.

Comment: If he's using C++11 yes. Added to answer thanks.

Comment: why not just reserve + emplace_back??

Comment: @billz Added your suggestion. We don't know if he's using C++11 though.

Comment: @EricFortin Why wouldn't he be?

Comment: @Ben Depends on what he is working on. I can't always use it in my day to day. On PS3 or X360 for example. Also compiler don't always compile in C++11 by default.

Comment: I think it's pretty safe to assume he can use c++11. It looks like he's learning to me. c++11 is only going to get more support, no point giving him old solutions.

Comment: That's why I updated the answer base on your suggestions. Although copy constructor is still needed in case he's not using an rvalue in the call to push_back.

Comment: How's that not an rvalue?

Comment: If I have `C c(2); vec.push_back(c);` It is not safe to move right ? I might be wrong. In that case I'll remove the comment.

Comment: Yeah. In that case it needs to be copied. But in his example, it is an rvalue, unless I'm missing something.

Comment: @Ben No you're right in his example it is. But this might not be his real code so that's why I prefer to specify.

Comment: Yeah, that's fair enough.

Comment: Of course you are right, thank you. As others in comments. A silly question. Sure no questions about using pointers.

Answer (score 1):

constructor C: 1

is called for creating temporary object C( 1 ) as argument of vec.push_back(i+1);
 when i =0

destructor C: 1

this temporary object was copied in an object of the vector and after that it was deleted.

constructor C: 2

is called for creating temporary object C( 2 ) as argument of vec.push_back(i+1);
 when i =1

The vecttor need to allocate a new memory region that to accomodate the second element. So it reallocates the memory and copies the first element in the new memory.

If you would call member function reserve

```
vector<C> vec;
vec.reserve( 2 );
```

then there would not be the reallocation and you would not see the next output.

destructor C: 1

the first element of the vector in old region memory is deleted

destructor C: 2

the temporary object was copied in an object of the vector and after that it was deleted.